# JAGS (Just Another Gibbs Sampler) installation from Terminal

Tags: command-line

I just one to know how can I install JAGS from the Ubuntu Terminal. Thanks.

Comment: `sudo apt-get install jags`.  See related [documentation/howto](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AptGet/Howto)

Comment: I guess that's the answer @earthmeLon - would be great if you'd post it as one

Comment: @Zanna Last time I posted something like that as an answer, it received the message "Trivial answer converted to comment".  Let me see if I can expand upon it this time.

Comment: it should have been fine @earthmeLon but I don't know the context. Maybe you can point it out to me. I think your answer is rather over-expanded, but +1 anyway

Comment: @earthmeLon a short answer with a link to another post on the same site gets converted to a comment, but that particular comment should be fine.

Answer (score 10):

Ubuntu uses `apt` as a [package manager](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Package_manager).  A package manager is software that helps you to manage other software installed on the system.  Instead of downloading binaries from a website, you typically use the package manager to install software from repositories. This is the safest and easiest way to install software on Ubuntu, so since JAGS is available in the Ubuntu repositories, you should install it with APT.

#### Update Available Software

In order for `apt` to work, it needs to know which versions, and what software is available.  `apt` only knows which packages are available by creating a database local to your machine.  You need to update this periodically, and typically before installing new software.

```
sudo apt-get update
```

#### Install a package

```
sudo apt-get install jags
```

#### Remove a Package

```
sudo apt-get remove jags
```

#### Search for Packages

```
sudo apt-cache search jags
```

#### Update (Upgrade) Installed Software

Once you have updated your list of software available on the repositories using `apt-get update`, you can tell `apt` to *upgrade* your packages.  This means that you want `apt` to install the latest available versions of software installed on your system

```
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

---

So, typically in order to install something, one may do something such as:

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install jags
```

To update your system and installed software:

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
```

---

See [Ubuntu Community Documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AptGet/Howto) as well as `apt` [man pages](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/zesty/man8/apt-get.8.html).